# Scraping with Beautifulsoup-Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape the name of the hotel in the tripadvisor in each review page of the hotel.

I wrote a code in python which is very simple and I think that it isn't false.

But every time it stops at a different point(page for example the first time stopped in page 150 second time in the page 330).

I am 100% that my code are correct. Is there any possibility that tripadvisor block me every time?

I update the code and i use selenium too but the problem is still remain

The updated code is the following:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os
import urllib.request
import time
import re

file2 = open(os.path.expanduser(r"~/Desktop/TripAdviser Reviews2.csv"), "wb")

file2.write(b"hotel,Address,HelpCount,HotelCount,Reviewer" + b"\n")

Checker ="REVIEWS"

# example option: add 'incognito' command line arg to options
option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_argument("--incognito")

# create new instance of chrome in incognito mode
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/Users/thimios/AppData/Local/Google/chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=option)
#print(browser)


# go to website of interest
for i in range(10,50,10):
    Websites=["https://www.tripadvisor.ca/Hotel_Review-g190479-d3587956-Reviews-or"+str(i)+"-The_Thief-Oslo_Eastern_Norway.html#REVIEWS"]
    print(Websites)
    for theurl in Websites:
        thepage=browser.get(theurl)
        thepage1 = urllib.request.urlopen(theurl)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(thepage1, "html.parser")
        # wait up to 10 seconds for page to load
        timeout = 5
        try:
            WebDriverWait(browser, timeout).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="HEADING"]')))
            #print(WebDriverWait(browser, timeout).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="HEADING"]'))))
        except TimeoutException:
            print("Timed out waiting for page to load")
            browser.quit()


        # Extract the helpful votes, hotel reviews
        helpcountarray = ""
        hotelreviewsarray = ""

        for profile in soup.findAll(attrs={"class": "memberBadging g10n"}):
            image = profile.text.replace("\n", "|||||").strip()
            #print(image)

            if image.find("helpful vote") > 0:
                counter = re.findall('\d+', image.split("helpful vote", 1)[0].strip()[-4:])
                if len(helpcountarray) == 0:
                    helpcountarray = [counter]
                else:
                    helpcountarray.append(counter)
            elif image.find("helpful vote") < 0:
                if len(helpcountarray) == 0:
                    helpcountarray = ["0"]
                else:
                    helpcountarray.append("0")
            print(helpcountarray)
            #print(len(helpcountarray))

            if image.find("hotel reviews") > 0:
                counter = re.findall('\d+', image.split("hotel reviews", 1)[0].strip()[-4:])
                if len(hotelreviewsarray) == 0:
                    hotelreviewsarray = counter
                else:
                    hotelreviewsarray.append(counter)
            elif image.find("hotel reviews") < 0:
                if len(hotelreviewsarray) == 0:
                    hotelreviewsarray = ['0']
                else:
                    hotelreviewsarray.append("0")
            print(hotelreviewsarray)
            #print(len(hotelreviewsarray))


        hotel_element = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="HEADING"]')
        Address_element = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="HEADING_GROUP"]/div/div[3]/address/div/div[1]')

        for i in range(0,10):
            print(i)
            for x in hotel_element:
                hotel = x.text
                print(hotel)
                #print(type(hotel))
            for y in Address_element:
                Address = y.text.replace(',', '').replace('\n', '').strip()
                print(Address)
                #print(type(Address))

            HelpCount = helpcountarray[i]
            HelpCount = " ".join(str(w) for w in HelpCount)
            print(HelpCount)
            #print(type(HelpCount))
            HotelCount = hotelreviewsarray[i]
            HotelCount = " ".join(str(w) for w in HotelCount)
            print(HotelCount)
            #print(type(HotelCount))
            Reviewer = soup.findAll(attrs={"class": "username mo"})[i].text.replace(',', ' ').replace('”', '').replace('“', '').replace('"', '').strip()
            print(Reviewer)


            Record2 = hotel + "," + Address +"," + HelpCount +"," + HotelCount+"," +Reviewer

            if Checker == "REVIEWS":
                file2.write(bytes(Record2, encoding="ascii", errors='ignore') + b"\n")


file2.close()
```

I read somewhere that I should add a header. Something like

```
headers={'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36'}
```

in order for the web site to allow me to scrape it. Is that true?

Thanks for your help

Comment: I don't know for trip advisor specifically but websites tend to try to protect their data from scrapping. Changing your user-agent regulary or your IP can help you pass through their filter

Comment: most websites allow scraping but at a very limited rate.check if its legal to scrape from tripadvisor and if so make at max 1 QPS( query/Sec)

Comment: @anekix. Thanks for your hint!! How can i make max 1QPS?Any suggestions?

Comment: look for `sleep()` function from `time` module. since your code is synchronnous , a simple call to `sleep` function will work

Comment: @anekix Thank you!!!. I 'll try it!!!

Comment: @anekix Unfortunately didn't work it -)

Comment: what error message you get ? what is the status code when error happens?

Comment: @anekix . AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'. The code doesn't stop in the same page everytime

Comment: status code....?

Comment: @anekix. 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/thimios/PycharmProjects/TripadvisorScrapping/First.py", line 36, in <module>
    Organization=soup.find('h1',{'class': 'heading_name'}).text.strip()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: status code of `http` request

Comment: @anekix . Sorry Anekix I am new in Python. I don't know what status code is???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. there is such a possibility.

Websites use to prevent web scraping, such as detecting and disallowing bots from crawling (viewing) their pages.

The default User-Agent typically refers to automated processes implemented using a python software, so you will want to change it to browser like User-Agent.

Even though, I do not believe you were blocked by TripAdvisor.

Answer (score 0):

Try to slow down the downloading by

```
import time
...
time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: well, then may be it's time to try some heavy artillery like Selenium? ) it allows to use real browser so you will act like a real user on a website

Answer (score 0):

No, try REAL life slowing it down, using Backoff so the target website doesn't think you're a bot...

```
import time

for term in ["web scraping", "web crawling", "scrape this site"]:
    t0 = time.time()
    r = requests.get("http://example.com/search", params=dict(
        query=term
    ))
    response_delay = time.time() - t0
    time.sleep(10*response_delay)  # wait 10x longer than it took them to respond
```

source:
https://blog.hartleybrody.com/web-scraping-cheat-sheet/#delays-and-backing-off